# How to use integration in Nonlinear Data-Fitting: Fsumsquares and then fminunc for parameter optimization

Tags: matlab, integral, non-linear

I am able to run the code for any equations but when I introduce an integral the command won't run:

```
    t=dataset_TK1(:,1);
dataset_TK4=xlsread('Akis','Sheet1','AG491:AR725');
y_4=dataset_TK4(:,12);

Kg=1.76717865712934;
N0=1.08E+05;

fun1=@(Z) Z^(-1+(X(1)-Kg)/X(3))*exp(Z);

Ntotal=@(X,t)integral(fun1,X(2)*exp(-X(3)*t),X(2));

X0=[10,10,10];
Fsumsquares=@(X)sum((Ntotal(X,t)-y_4).^2);
opts = optimoptions('fminunc','Algorithm','quasi-newton');
[xunc,ressquared,eflag,outputu] =   fminunc(Fsumsquares,X0,opts)
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: I suppose the limits of the integral should be scalars, cannot be computed runtime with a function.

Comment: `fun1` should be `fun1 = @(X,Z)` maybe ? Your code lacks the `X` there is just `Z` under the handle

Comment: But I have to take every point in time. Is there a suggested approach?

Comment: `X(1)` and `X(3)` in `fun1`, but `X` is not defined, at least not in your code snippet.

Comment: It is defined in the way the Fsumsquares function operates.

Comment: but also `t` is in the handle of `Ntotal`, but is also defined in the first line of the code snippet. `X` is not defined instead, but treated the same as `t`. `Ntotal` has its parameters defined when called in `Fsumsquares`, while `fun1` has no parameter defined when it is called by `Ntotal`. I think function parameters should all be treated the same.

Comment: If you read the theory of the function you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The MWE (minimum working example) code below works, in the sense it doesn't spurt out errors: to obtain it, I have substituted your excel data with dummy arrays.

I limited myself to remove unnecessary handles from functions in your snippet, and adjust operators to element-wise `.^` and `.*` in `fun1`.
Also, in the `Ntotal` integral, the limits should be scalars, not vectors. That is why I took only one element out of `t`:

```
% dummies, put your data back
t=ones(1,10);
y_4=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
X=[11,3,4,6,2,3,55,22,89,6];

Kg=1.76717865712934;
N0=1.08E+05;

fun1=@(Z) Z.^(-1+(X(1)-Kg)/X(3)).*exp(Z);               % changed
Ntotal=integral(fun1,X(2)*exp(-X(3)*t(1)),X(2));        % changed

X0=[10,10,10];
Fsumsquares=@(X) sum((Ntotal-y_4).^2);                  % changed
opts = optimoptions('fminunc','Algorithm','quasi-newton');
[xunc,ressquared,eflag,outputu] =   fminunc(Fsumsquares,X0,opts)
```